# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u_n}{n}$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $u_n>u_{n+1}>0$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$, and suppose that $u_2+u_4+u_8+u_{16}+\dots$ diverges. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u_n}{n}$diverges.

Please provide me a hint or a full solution.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you read about the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: think about the partial sums
$$ S_k = \sum_{n = 2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{u_n}n$$

Notice that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u_n}n = u_1 + \frac{u_2}2 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty S_k$$
so it's enough to show that the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^\infty S_k$ diverges.

Notice that the terms in the partial sums $S_k$ are decreasing.  Therefore the smallest term in the sum is the last one, $\frac{u_{2^{k+1}}}{2^{k+1}}$.

As there are $2^k$ terms in each sum we must have
$$\sum_{n = 2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}} \frac{u_n}n \geq 2^{k} \frac{u_{2^{k+1}}}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{u_{2^{k+1}}}{2} $$

So $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u_n}n \geq u_1 + \frac 12\left(u_2 + u_4 + u_8 + \dots\right)$$which we are given as divergent.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}\frac{u_n}{n}
>\sum_{n=2^m}^{2^{m+1}-1}\frac{u_{2^{m+1}}}{2^{m+1}}
= 2^m \frac{u_{2^{m+1}}}{2^{m+1}}
=u_{2^{m+1}}/2
$.

Therefore
$\sum_{n=1}^{2^m-1} \frac{u_n}{n}
> \frac1{2}\sum_{k=1}^m u_{2^k} 
$
and, if the latter sum diverges, so does the former.

Note that an almost identical argument will show that
if $(a_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$
is an increasing sequence of positive integers
such that there is a $c < 1$ such that
$\frac{a_{m}}{a_{m+1}} \le c$ for all $m$,
and $u_n \ge u_{n+1}$ for all $n$,
then $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} u_{a_m}$ diverges
implies that 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{u_n}{n}$ diverges.

Here is the proof by copy and paste:

$\sum_{n=a_m}^{a_{m+1}-1}\frac{u_n}{n}
>\sum_{n=a_m}^{a_{m+1}-1}\frac{u_{a_{m+1}}}{a_{m+1}}
= (a_{m+1}-a_m) \frac{u_{a_{m+1}}}{a_{m+1}}
=(1-\frac{a_{m}}{a_{m+1}})u_{a_{m+1}}
=(1-c)u_{a_{m+1}}
$.
Therefore
$\sum_{n=1}^{a_m-1} \frac{u_n}{n}
> (1-c)\sum_{k=1}^m u_{a_k} 
$
and, if the latter sum diverges, so does the former.

The fact that $1-\frac{a_{m}}{a_{m+1}}$
occurs leads to the requirement on $a_m$.

We can also go the other way
and see what is needed.

$\sum_{n=a_m}^{a_{m+1}-1}\frac{u_n}{n}
<\sum_{n=a_m}^{a_{m+1}-1}\frac{u_{a_{m}}}{a_{m}}
= (a_{m+1}-a_m) \frac{u_{a_{m}}}{a_m}
=(\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}-1)u_{a_{m}}
$.

From this we see that if
$\frac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}-1 < d$
for some real $d$ and all $m$,
then
$u_{a_{m}} > \frac1{d}\sum_{n=a_m}^{a_{m+1}-1}\frac{u_n}{n}$,
so that
$\sum \frac{u_n}{n}$ diverges
implies that 
$\sum u_{a_m}$ diverges.

Combining these two,
we get this:

If $(a_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$
is an increasing sequence of positive integers
such that there exists positive reals $c$ and $d$ such that
$c \le \frac{a_{m+1}}{a_{m}}-1 \le d$ for all $m$,
and $u_n \ge u_{n+1}$ for all $n$,
then $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} u_{a_m}$ converges
if and only if 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{u_n}{n}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ u_n = (\log n)^{-1}$

Comment: Both sums diverge: $1/(n \log n)$ and $1/\log(2^n) = 1/(n \log 2)$.